# Json format with Play 2.4 / Scala

Tags: json, scala, format, playframework-2.4

I know this question has been asked thousand times but I can't figure why this code cannot work properly.

```
case class Partner
(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, beacon: Option[Beacon])

class PartnerFormatter @Inject() (val beaconDao: BeaconDao){
  implicit val partnerReads: Reads[Partner] = (
      (__ \ "_id").readNullable[String]and
      (__ \ "name").read[String] and
      (__ \ "beacon").read[String]
    )((_id, name, beaconID) => Partner(_id.map(BSONObjectID(_)), name, Await.result(beaconDao.findById(beaconID), 1 second))))

  implicit val partnerWrites: Writes[Partner] = (
        (JsPath \ "_id").writeNullable[String].contramap((id: Option[BSONObjectID]) => Some(id.get.stringify)) and
        (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
        (JsPath \ "beacon").writeNullable[String].contramap((beacon: Option[Beacon]) => Some(beacon.get._id.get.stringify))
      )(unlift(Partner.unapply))
}
```

And I'm facing

```
No Json deserializer found for type models.Partner. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type
```

Or

```
No Json deserializer found for type models.Partner. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type
```

Shouldn't it be working ?

Comment: make sure those implicits are actually present where the conversion happens

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure about the details on Play, but with Spray it's usually that I'm missing some imports. I just fixed the same issue myself on an AkkaHttp service and it was missing this import at the top of the file: import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._

I hope this gets you on the right track

Comment: Try defining implicits in a companion object for Partner if you could.

Comment: I can make it works but without using implicit property. I specify it. But i know that in other simple projects, imports does the trick but here not. I think it's the class instead of object for companion

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the readers and writers in Partner *object*.

This is an example, https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/blob/master/app/models/User.scala

Comment: I suspected it. By the way I changed my code so I don't need to anymore, but thanks for your reply :)